# Opening Colloquy with xdcc links

Tags: irc, ios, protocol, colloquy

I'd like to set the application Colloquy to open with the xdcc:// protocol links, in OS lion.
Generally, I don't know how to associate a single application to a protocol in Chrome.
help! :P